# Extimating the repartition of water between hygroscopic compounds

Tags: physical-chemistry, aqueous-solution, desiccation

Sulfuric acid is sometimes used as a drying agent.

According to literature, one possible application is, for instance, in the drying of bromine.

Some questions came to my mind: which concentration of sulfuric acid would be suitable for such a task? Under which concentration would the acid stop absorbing water from bromine, and there would then be an "equilibrium" between the water bound to bromine and that bound to sulfuric acid?

To put the problem in a general and less specific way: is there a way to estimate the capability of a compound to "catch" water from another compound, and in case of liquid compounds or of hemihydrated molecules, to estimate the maximum amount of water present before an equal repartition of water between the two substances occurs?

I was thinking about the enthalpies of hydration, but I honestly didn't come up with an idea for using them in such calculations.

Comment: It's characterised by equilibrium water vapor pressure over agent.